# Quiz in Python - Original program ran, but refactored and does not run now

Tags: python, csv, oop, random, import

Simple quiz in Python that reads a csv file in "answer,question" format. The program was running before I decided to try to refactor my original code. I referenced different sources to determine whether the csv, random, classes and loop were coded correctly, but the code does not run with this updated refactored version.

**Original Code**

```
player_name = input("What is your name? ")
print(f"Welcome, {player_name}, to Quiz!")
play_quiz = str(input("Are you ready to play?\n"))
if play_quiz != "y":
    exit()

class Question:
    def __init__(self, prompt, answer):
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.answer = answer

# sample quiz questions go here where ["Question", "Answer choices from a-c"]
question_prompts = []

questions = [
        Question(question_prompts[0], "b"),
        Question(question_prompts[1], "a"),
    ]

def run_test(questions):
    score = 0
    for question in questions:
        answer = input(question.prompt)
        if answer == question.answer:
            score += 1
        print("You answered " + str(score) + "/" + str(len(questions)) + " correct.")

    return input("Want to play again? (y/n): ") == "y".lower()

play_again = True
while play_again:
    play_again = run_test(questions)
```

**Refactored Code**

```
import csv
import random 

player_name = input("What is your name? ")
print(f"Welcome, {player_name}, to the Quiz!")
play_quiz = str(input("Are you ready to play? "))
if play_quiz != "y":
    exit()

class Question:
    def __init__(self, prompt, answer):
        self.prompt = prompt
        self.answer = answer

def quiz():
    score = 0
    questions_right = 0
    quiz_file = open(characters_file, "r")
    quiz_data = quiz_file.readlines()
    random.shuffle(quiz_data)
    question_number = 1 
    for question in range(65):
         x = quiz_data[question].strip()
         data = x.split(",")
         Question = data.prompt[1]
         correct_answer = data.answer[1]

def run_test(quiz_data):
    answer = input("What is your answer? ")
    if answer == correct_answer:
         score += 1
         question_right = question_number + 1
    else:
         print("Incorrect.")
         print(f"Correct answer should be: {CorrectAnswer}")

    total_score = (score / 65) * 100 
    print("You answered " + str(score) + "/" + str(total_score) + " question correct.")
    print("You have a score of " + str(total_score) + "%")

    return input("Want to play again? (y/n): ") == "y".lower()

 quiz()
 quiz_file.close()
 play_again = True
 while play_again:
     play_again = run_test()
```

I do not see what am I doing wrong for it not run with the refactored code below. In essence, what am I doing wrong? Am I putting the code in the wrong place for it not run?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you share the code of your original program?

Comment: You never do anything with your `Question` class, what is the point of even defining it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are incorrectly using the `Question` class you made. You try to do `Question = data.prompt[1]` which doesn't really make sense. Question is a class and therefore you would use it to create *instances* of the object. Furthermore, your class expects the values `prompt` and `answer` to be passed to it. The way you have it setup now you would do something along the lines of `new_question = Question("What color is the sky?", "blue")`. However, I do not see much use to creating a class in this code because you have no methods attached to it...

Here is an example of a quiz class idea that may help you grasp the concept of OOP programming:

```
import random

questions = [
    "What color is the sky?",
    "What year is it?"
]

answers = [
    "blue",
    "2019"
]

class Question:
    def __init__(self):
        index = random.randint(0, len(questions) - 1)
        self.answer = answers[index]
        self.question = questions[index]

    def check_valid(self, guess):
        if guess == self.answer:
            return True
        else:
            return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    name = str(input("What's your name?\n"))
    print('Welcome then {} welcome to the quiz!'.format(name))
    while True:
        new_question = Question()
        check = False
        while check is not True:
            print(new_question.question)
            user_guess = str(input('What do you think the answer is?\n'))
            check = new_question.check_valid(user_guess)
```

You can see that during the `__init__(self):` section the code doesn't really do any major calculations, but just sets up things that can later be called like `new_question.question`. However, you can attach *methods* to the class like `check_valid` (attached to the class by indentation of `def`) and then later on use these methods on the *instances* of the class you create. There are many functions not present in my code (the ability to exit the loop for example) but hopefully this will help you understand OOP at a slightly deeper level!

Comment: If this answered your question you can click the check mark next to my post to accept it as the answer you were looking for